# SQL Server : index ignored based on Execution Plan

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing

I have a stored procedure that runs this statement

```
UPDATE QP.LocalMessage WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK) 
SET StatusId = 0 
WHERE StatusId = 1 AND DateLockedUntil <= @DateNow
```

and we have created an index for this update to run quickly

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_LocalMessage_ProcessingLocked] 
    ON [QP].[LocalMessage] ([DateLockedUntil] ASC)
    WHERE ([StatusId] = (1))
```

But after look at the execution plan being used we are not using this index and it's using a clustered index scan instead. This would need this statement to be executed under 2 seconds at least, but we are seeing time when it goes up to 12-15 seconds. I would like to understand why it's ignoring the index.

Comment: I can think 2 reasons. 1. The store procedure was already compiled and the plan stored (you can test WITH RECOMPILE) and 2. SQL Server finds that using that index would take the same time as using the PK. Maybe you can try INCLUDE(ing) the fields you'll need in that index

Comment: Questions: 1) what version of SQL Server,? 2) what is the execution plan's estimate of how many rows it will be updating? 3) how many rows are in the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a nonclustered index, SQL Server needs to do a key lookup operation. In a select statement this can be avoided with covering queries, in update statement this can't be avoided.

If the number of records returned by the predicate is large, it will be better to do a clustered scan than the nonclustered index seek and key lookups.

Your query is parameterized, so SQL Server is unable to be sure of the number of records that will be returned. You could be updating the entire table.

If some of the executions update only a few records and could use the nonclustered index seek, than you can configure your procedure with the "with recompile" clause. This will allow SQL Server to analyze the plan for each parameter value your procedure receives. Another option is to use "option (recompile)" in your query.

However, keep in mind that SQL Server will only use the nonclustered index if the number of records being updated is small.

You can also prove all I'm saying by using "(index=yourindexname)" as a query hint besides your table name and analyze the statistics io and statistics time to notice how bad it is when it uses the nonclustered index seek in a query it shouldn't do this.

Comment: I believe You I've changed the query and now it's using the index. Even in our dev environment when there were 0 records in status one it took 1 minute to run. now less than 1 second : UPDATE LME WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK) 
    SET StatusId = 0
 FROM  QP.LocalMessage AS LME WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK) 
 INNER JOIN 
  (
   SELECT Id  FROM QP.LocalMessage  WHERE StatusId = 1 
  ) as ONE ON ONE.Id = LME.Id 
    WHERE 
        StatusId = 1 
    AND DateLockedUntil <= @DateNow

Answer (score 2):

If you `include (StatusId)` then your query can use your filtered index.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_LocalMessage_ProcessingLocked_Include] 
    ON [QP].[LocalMessage] ([DateLockedUntil] ASC)
    include (StatusId)
    WHERE ([StatusId] = (1))
```

dbfiddle: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=816af692f8993ce8844b5b5c7182f7a1

---

Reference:

- [Filtered Indexes: Just Add Includes - Erik Darling](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/12/filtered-indexes-just-add-includes/)

Comment: Thanks for the refernce I assumed it would know to use the Index because its also filtered by the same statusId. It was a good read. Also I never heard on dbfiddle before. It looks amazing! who created this? Also I added the change i made using the inner join. It seems it still is faster than using the include of the Include in the index. The only possible issue is the "Table Spool" which if there are alot of records could be a perfomance hit http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=5b860487035b466690e885c384a57550

Comment: @greektreat Jack Douglas made dbfiddle.uk [A new fiddle for dba.se](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2686/43889)